# Working with multiple processes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multiprocessing

Is there a module for Ruby that makes it easy to share objects between multiple processes?  I'm looking for something similar to Python's [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html), which supports process-safe queues and pipes that can be shared between processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining DRb, which provides simple inter-process communication, with Queue or SizedQueue, which are both threadsafe queues, should give you what you need.

You may also want to check out [beanstalkd](http://xph.us/software/beanstalkd/) which is also hosted on [github](http://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/tree/master)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do a lot of what you want using the facilities of Ruby IO; you're sharing between processes, not threads, correct?

If that's the case, IO.pipe will do what you need.  Ruby doesn't have any built-in way of handling cross-process queues (to my knowledge), but you can also use FIFOs (if you're on Unix).

If you want something more fine-grained, and with good threading support, I'm fairly certain that you can piggyback on java.util.concurrent if you use JRuby.  MRI has pretty lousy threading/concurrency support, so if that's what your aiming for, JRuby is probably a better place to go.

Comment: I've used it in both perl and ruby. It's freaking awesome.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this library but I haven't tried it yet.

Parallel::ForkManager — A simple parallel processing fork manager.

http://parallelforkmgr.rubyforge.org/