# What is Ruby's equivalent to Python's multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, ruby, concurrency, parallel-processing

To get real concurrency in Ruby or Python, I need to create new processes. Python makes this pretty straightforward using the `multiprocessing` module, which abstracts away all the fork / wait goodness and lets me concentrate on my code. Does Ruby have something similar? Right now I am calling `Process.fork` and `Process.wait` to get my concurrency, and I want a cleaner solution.

Comment: Not really an answer to the question but: Ruby uses native threads for a while now, so threads are actually a very good way to get "real" concurrency. Plus, you don't need to worry about shared data structures etc. (apart from the obvious thread-safety)

Comment: Have you already gone through this [one][1]?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855805/please-introduce-a-multi-processing-library-in-perl-or-ruby

Comment: @Niklas: I'm stuck with Ruby 1.8 at work :(

Comment: @Bourne: None of those options seemed quite satisfactory. DRb / beanstalkd seem like overkill, since I don't need to communicate between processes. I just want a simple wrapper around fork/exec.

Comment: One of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710785/working-with-multiple-processes-in-ruby) suggests [Parallel::ForkManager](http://parallelforkmgr.rubyforge.org/), which may fit your needs better.

Comment: @NiklasB. Although Ruby uses Native threads, it has a Global VM Lock (GVL) which prevents multiple Ruby thread from executing simultaneously (even if there is more than one core). So on MRI/YARV, the only way to achieve true parallelism is with multiple processes.

Comment: @Thayne: I stand corrected, and I have learned better in the 2 and a half years that lie between now and the time of my original comment (: Anyhow, we can use Rubinius now, which doesn't need the GIL because it's not nearly as big a hack as MRI is...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used https://github.com/grosser/parallel, and like it a lot. It will #map or #each across all the cores in your system by default. Under the hood it's a wrapper around Process.fork, which sounds like what you're asking for.

Comment: The only issue with Parallel is that it does not allow me to do anything after forking. It always waits for the tasks to complete.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pmahoney/process_shared let me know if you have any feature requests for it :)