# Why does this multithreaded program not work as intended?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I wrote a test program. In short, it does the following:

1. executes some random useless calcuations (but long enough) in single thread and prints execution
   time
2. executes same program in 6 threads and prints execution time

Now, in both cases execution time is the same. What am I doing wrong?
Here are the sources:

```
def time
  start = Time.now
  yield
  p Time.now - start
end


range_limit = 9999
i_exponent = 9999

time do
  array = (1 .. range_limit).map { |i | i**i_exponent }
  p (array.inject(:+)/2)[0]
end

time do
  first_thread = Thread.new do
    arr = (1..range_limit/6).map { |i| i**i_exponent }
    arr.inject(:+)
  end

  second_thread = Thread.new do
    arr = (range_limit/6..range_limit*2/6).map { |i| i**i_exponent }
    arr.inject(:+)
  end

  third_thread = Thread.new do
    arr = (range_limit*2/6..range_limit*3/6).map { |i| i**i_exponent }
    arr.inject(:+)
    end

  fourth_thread = Thread.new do
    arr = (range_limit*3/6..range_limit*4/6).map { |i| i**i_exponent }
    arr.inject(:+)
    end

  fifth_thread = Thread.new do
    arr = (range_limit*4/6..range_limit*5/6).map { |i| i**i_exponent }
    arr.inject(:+)
  end

  sixth_thread = Thread.new do
    arr = (range_limit*5/6..range_limit).map { |i| i**i_exponent }
    arr.inject(:+)
  end

  first_thread.join
  second_thread.join
  third_thread.join
  fourth_thread.join
  fifth_thread.join
  sixth_thread.join

  result = first_thread.value + second_thread.value + third_thread.value + fifth_thread.value + sixth_thread.value

  p (result/2)[0]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpreters like Ruby and Python are not truly parallel while executing multiple threads - to protect the state of the interpreter, they have a [global VM lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) that [doesn't allow simultaneous execution](http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/).

To get the benefit of threads, you need to find a way to execute non-Ruby code that runs without the global lock, [use multiple processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264710/what-is-rubys-equivalent-to-pythons-multiprocessing-module) instead of threads. Another option is to switch to a ruby implementation that doesn't have the global lock, such as JRuby or Rubinius.

Comment: @Chelios Use multiple processes. I've now updated the answer with a link to a SO answer that offers some modules to make that easier.

Comment: If it's feasible to use a different Ruby implementations, that can solve your issue. Neither JRuby nor Rubinius have a GIL, and allow code to execute in parallel.

Comment: @JimmyCuadra I've updated the answer to mention alternative implementations.